# How to run Meteor forever? And is it good using 3rd party database?

Tags: javascript, meteor

So, when I run `meteor`, app works fine. However, when I close the connection to my cloud server, meteor obviously shuts down. What should I do to run meteor forever?

Also, what's the point of using 3rd party database service like https://mongolab.com/? Doesn't it slow down the website, because now application has to connect to their database instead of local database?

And how exactly do I connect to mongolab for example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So, when I run meteor, app works fine. However, when I close the
>   connection to my cloud server, meteor obviously shuts down.

You could launch meteor with `nohup` (no hang-up) which serves this purpose.

```
nohup meteor --production &
```

But it's not a good idea to run a site in production with meteor anyway.

> What should I do to run meteor forever ?

You can use `forever`, a Node.js tool designed to run node apps as services.

I also want to point that `forever` is getting old and I've heard of better recent alternatives but it seems to still be a pretty common tool.
You could also use `systemd` which integrates better with the UNIX service ecosystem but that's anoter story.

But first, you'll have to "demeteorize" your meteor application like this :

```
cd my-project-meteor
meteor bundle --directory ../my-project-node
# this is going to take some time
cd ../my-project-node/programs/server
npm install
# this is going to take some time too
```

So now you have a plain node app, that you can run with `node main.js`

Let me mention that it might be a good idea to use the node version used by meteor which is 0.10.29 as of meteor 0.9.1
You can install it traditionally or you could use the node version that is shipped with the meteor tool.

```
sudo ln -s ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.0.27/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node /usr/bin/node
sudo ln -s ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.0.27/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Note that this way of "installing" node + npm on your system is problematic because :

- it assumes you're doing only meteor related stuff.
- it is dependant on the release process of the meteor tool (you'll need to rerun these commends if the meteor tool is updated).

You can install the `forever` tool using npm :

```
# -g means globally : give access to forever to all users on the system
sudo npm install -g forever
```

To launch your node app as a service, you can use the following command, which sets correctly some environment variables and run the app using `forever` :

```
sudo PORT=80 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost/my-project-mongodb ROOT_URL=http://localhost forever start my-project-node/main.js
```

You can monitor it using `forever stop my-project-node/main.js`

> Also, what's the point of using 3rd party database service like
>   https://mongolab.com/?

When using the meteor tool, it launches a `mongod` process automatically for you, and the underlying node process executed by meteor representing your app connects to this mongo instance.

When we want to launch our meteor app as a node app, we have to handle the mongo stuff ourself, which kinda answer the question : why not using another service to handle it for us, they know better, right ?

> Doesn't it slow down the website, because now application has to
>   connect to their database instead of local database ?

Of course, relying on a 3rd party database service has its inconvenients, and this is one of them. Network communications will always be slower than interprocess communications taking place on localhost (this is especially true on these SSD backed cheap VPS you can find nowadays).

> And how exactly do I connect to mongolab for example ?

By setting an appropriate value to the environment variable `MONGO_URL`, the database service provider will give you an url that corresponds to your online `mongodb`, this is what you need to pass to the node process in command line if you want meteor to connect to your distant database and work as usual.

If you want to launch a dedicated local `mongod` instance to let your application connect to it, well this is another topic but you'll have to follow these steps :

- first install `mongodb` correctly on your server, using the reference documentation for the OS version. By correctly I mean choose the same version as meteor is using currently (2.4.9) and let it run as a service so that it will actually restart when your server reboots.
- test that mongod is running by launching a client with the `mongo` command.
- pass the correct MONGO_URL when launching your app with forever (something like `mongodb://localhost/my-project-mongodb`)

Understand now why `meteor deploy` is amazing :D

Comment: > But it's not a good idea to run a site in production with meteor anyway
 
why?

Comment: > Why use forever, if nohup does the job?

Comment: The meteor bundling process optimize your application for the current architecture so it will run faster. The advantage of forever over nohup is that if the node process app of your app crashes, forever will automatically relaunch it providing a theorical 100% uptime of your website. nohup is just a command to avoid the process launched with to stop when receiving the HUP (hangup) signal typically sent when you logout, but it is not, by any means, a serious service controller launcher.

Comment: thanks. I ran all your commands, get `Forever processing file: main.js`, but I can't see anything on my domain :( when I run simply meteor it works

Comment: `cd` to `~/.forever`, `ls` in there and you will see a bunch of .log files, `cat` them to see what's wrong : it could be an error while connecting to your local mongodb, a wrong `ROOT_URL`, etc... this will help diagnosing the problem.

Comment: interesting, there is one log file, but it's empty

Comment: btw, I am connecting to 3rd party database

Comment: It doesn't look good. You should start by trying to launch your app with node alone to see what it's complaining about. Can you provide the command line you're using to launch the node app ?

Comment: it says `Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment` when I run node main.js

Comment: Let's have a chat, ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60727/discussion-between-good-evening-and-saimeunt).