# How to keep meteor reliable in a production environment?

Tags: meteor, reliability

I'm currently developing an application in meteor and I'm worried what might happen if a serious bug (or anything) crashes the web application. I have never worked on a production application, but I've read how downtime can seriously impact a business.

I searched and I found this answer: [How to run Meteor forever? And is it good using 3rd party database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677701/how-to-run-meteor-forever-and-is-it-good-using-3rd-party-database)

The following link mostly answers my question using a node package called `Forever` which I've read is old and not an optimal solution for keeping node (in this case, meteor) running. Is `nohup` the best way? Are there any meteor packages or other ways to keep meteor running in the case of a crash?

Edit: I'm currently running Meteor on Fedora 22. I know there might be some open source solutions for this, but I'm not aware of them. Hopefully this might help anyone answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: is meteor production-ready?

Comment: Looks like it is (despite the 0.X version number)...

Comment: Meteor's latest version is 1.1.

Comment: Running an application in production is a big deal but it really depends on many variables. Are you hosting the server yourself? do you have to host it yourself or can someone on a cloud dot it for you? can you add redundancy or fail-over servers? Is the content of the application business critical? what are the consequences of having the server/app down for a few hours, days? How reliable do you want it to be? 99% uptime or 99.9999% (i.e. how many nines? the more nines you want, the more it costs). Too many things to consider for a quick answer. You should think PaaS or Platform as a Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple as everything in Meteor. Just use [Meteor up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) package for deployment and you are ready to go. Nothing scary.

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate it!